# Can't run 'mongorestore' with GLIBC 2.31

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

when I want to use the 'mongorestore' command, I got an error about the 'GLIBC' version that I'm using.

```
$ mongorestore --version
>> mongorestore: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by mongorestore)
>> mongorestore: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by mongorestore)
```

I'm using MongoDB 5.06 and Ubuntu 20.04, and got installed the next GLIBC version: '(Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.14) 2.31'

Can you help me with this problem?

I tried to use the 'Mongorestore' command in Ubuntu 20.04, with MongoDB 5.06 and GLIBC 2.31, but the message that I receive is that I need to update the GLIBC version to 2.32 or 2.34, but I don't have access to update this GLIBC in the virtual machine.

Comment: I don't know, but these kind of problems usually mean that you need to install an earlier version of `mongorestore`. The binary has this dependency and won't run unless it exists. Alternatively, you might have some luck installing Mongodb Shell in a contained environment, perhaps as a snap.